# Find duplicate column and separate them to a file or variable(Bash)

Tags: bash, awk

I have output like ; (The columns separated by tab `\t`)

```
name1   something1
name1   something2
name1   something3
name2   something4
name2   something5
```

For this output I need two output (if there is `name3`, I will need 3 output) like

```
name1   something1
name1   something2
name1   something3
```

and

```
name2   something4
name2   something5
```

I think this will be done by AWK but I couldn't create magic words.

What is the best way to do this?

I need a condition to read `$1` "1.column" and print all of them(not delete duplicates) unless it will change and print other columns ($2,$3,...)

I think using loop it prints first output and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print>$1;}' file
```

When the above command is complete, there will be two more files in the directory:

```
$ cat name1
name1   something1
name1   something2
name1   something3
$ cat name2
name2   something4
name2   something5
```

#### How it works

- `-F'\t'`

  This tells awk to use a tab as the field separator.
- `print>$1`

  This tells awk to print each line to the a file named after the first field.

#### Removing illegal characters from file names

Suppose the input file looks like:

```
$ cat file
name/1  something1
name/1  something2
name/1  something3
name/2  something4
name/2  something5
```

The following code creates files based on the name field but with the `/` removed:

```
awk -F'\t' '{name=$1; gsub(/[/]/, "", name); print>name;}' file
```

The above was tested on GNU awk and ran successfully. If your awk does not accept , then try:

```
awk -F'\t' '{name=$1; gsub("/", "", name); print>name;}' file
```

or:

```
awk -F'\t' '{name=$1; gsub(/\//, "", name); print>name;}' file
```

Comment: lol thats elegant!

Comment: AWK cannt open "name1" for output? It wont create a file?

Comment: @makgun That likely means that the command is being run in a directory for which you do not have _write_ permission.  Before running the command, `cd` to a directory that you own.

Comment: I am at $HOME in my bash-shell

Comment: The problem cause for meta charecters which doesnt allowed by system to be named a file like `: /`

Comment: Is there any way to be named it with incrementing filename instead of "$1"

Comment: @makgun See updated answer for a way to remove illegal characters from file names.

Comment: my output; 

`makgun@makgun02:~$ awk -F'\t' '{name=$1; gsub(/[/]/, "", name); print>name;}' random


awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (bad class -- [], [^] or [)


[


awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ]
`

Comment: Curious.  What OS are you using?  I updated the answer with two alternative ways to write that regex.  Give them a try.  P.S. Thanks for supplying the complete error message.

Comment: I used this command 

`awk -F'\t' '{name=$1; gsub(/[\/]/, "", name); print>name;}' file` with escaping `/` with using `\\` after this it creates files +1

Comment: @John1024 Long time later, I am again here, I need  a command to do this to an array variable. I used `for loop ` to put them into array but if there is a file which is named as `name` output in current dir  , it overwrites . So How can I DO assign them to an array? It must be assign in awk and also it must be recallable outside of awk (in current shell).

Comment: @makgun To append, rather than overwrite, replace `>` with `>>` : `awk -F'\t' '{print>>$1;}' file` .

Comment: Thanks @John1024. Appending it not useful for my script but I solved this issue via using `awk and for loop` echo "$var" | awk '{print $1}' | awk '!a[$0]++' --->>> this gives me all $1 as string and I assigned all of them as array. After that I created forloop to re call array and then assigned them a new array (i used `newarray[$i]=$(awk -v a=${a[$i]} '{if ($1 == a) print $0}')` this condition and for loop.)($i is in ${!a[*]})

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
mkdir tmp; cd tmp
while IFS= read line; do
    echo "$line" >> $(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
done
cat *
```

This reads input line by line and appends each line accordingly to it's first argument.

If you want to stream it to variable:

```
while IFS= read line; do
    key="$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')"
    eval "INPUT_$key='\$INPUT_$key\$line'"
done
```

If you have big demands from it, use:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import re

for line in sys.stdin:
    f = open(re.split("\s+", line, 1), 'a')
    f.write(line)
    f.close()
```

This will work. Must. It can't fail.

Comment: With this , it prints just $1 and it wont find last line if it changes

Comment: @makgun, it will, if you press enter.

Comment: I created bash script and I added this to file with adding `< <(cat $file)` after `done` but it didnt work

Comment: @makgun, if you are planning to use all kinds of characters on all platforms, don't use `bash`/`awk`/`gawk`/etc, use `perl`/`python`.

Comment: I don't know how phyton works and I need to change all previous command to get this my first output